# bootstrap tooltip placement not right when using icon font

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to make it so when someone hovers over an icon on my website a tooltip shows up below the icon (using bootstrap) but the placement of the tool tip is all messed up.

Here is my code

```
<a id='notify' href="#" 
   data-toggle="tooltip" 
   data-placement="bottom" 
   data-content="Vivamus sagittis lacus vel augue laoreet rutrum faucibus." 
   title="" 
   data-original-title="Popover on top">
  <i class = 'icon-globe'></i>
</a>
```

AND MY SCRIPT

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $("#notify").tooltip();
      });
```

I have tried just using plain text and it works fine but when I use an icon font the placement of my tooltip is to the right and not even close to the icon font

here is a screen shot:

[image]

Thanks

---

EDIT: SOLVED

---

I ran into this issue again today and solved it by moving the tooltip attributes from the link tag to the i tag like so

BEFORE

```
<a id='notify' href="#" 
   data-toggle="tooltip" 
   data-placement="bottom" 
   data-content="Vivamus sagittis lacus vel augue laoreet rutrum faucibus." 
   title="" 
   data-original-title="Popover on top">
  <i class = 'icon-globe'></i>
</a>
```

AFTER

Comment: Have you added any extra styling to that icon? This generally should not happen since tooltip uses relative position.

Comment: yes i think i did add extra styling, i ended up just writing my own tooltip popups for this specific thing.. I just made the div around each icon position relative and made the tooltip positioned absolute within that icon div